# What is the best way to store a result set for later use?

Tags: postgresql

I have a spatial query that does some very heavy geometry based maths to get a result set. That result set is then used to do all kinds of subsequent queries as the user interacts with my front end application.

The spatial query is very heavy so I would like to store the results, then re-use that result set for the subsequent queries.

At the moment I'm thinking about storing the id's in tmp file an then passing them as an array to subsequent SQL queries. The array could be huge, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: PostgreSQL Version ???

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a WITH query could help with this, but maybe a better solution might be a MATERIALIZED VIEW, which you can REFRESH to store the new result, and then call in essentially the same way in subsequent queries.

[CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)